# Redirect To Login Page After Submit In MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, authentication, simplemembership

after submit action for this view- browser redirect to login page!!

even for authenticated user

(mvc4-vs2012-simplemembership)

View:

```
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Comment"))
{
    <fieldset> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span8">
                    @if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <div class="iran text-success">
                            <i class="icon-user"></i>
                            username:<span>@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ArticleId" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.TextArea("Description", new { @Class = "span6", @Rows = 4 })
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <span class="span4">
                                <p>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit comment" />
                                </p>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="iran">
                            @Html.ActionLink("you must first log in", "LoginUser", "Account")
                        </div>
                    }
....
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
{
    try
    {    
        var ins = new Comment();
            ins.Description = form["Description"];
            ins.ArticleId = Convert.ToInt16(form["ArticleId"]);
            ins.DateSend = Shamsi();
            ins.TimeSend = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            ins.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
            bank.Comments.InsertOnSubmit(ins);
            bank.SubmitChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
    catch { return null;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code. Hidden field "ArticleId" cannot be cast to int because it is null. This error message is being swallowed up in the try-catch block and you are not observing and/or being notified of it. Once this is fixed you still may have additional problems. I would recommend to remove the try-catch while debugging. I would also recommend to check the "ModelState" to make sure it is valid, such as making sure all fields are entered, prior to saving.

Comment: I Put A Break Point In The First Line Defination of ActionResult Create(Comment Controller) And I realized that Program Not be Redirected To Comment Controller!!

Comment: Does your controller have any sort of authorize/authentication filters that would prevent a user from accessing this method? You can specify filters at the controller and/or action level... it might look this "[Authorize]".

Comment: Something is intercepting the HTTP POST and determining that the user must log in. This is commonly done by controller/action filters. Can you post more of the application code?